# Removing a javscript from homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, xml

i am trying to remove the validation.js script from my home page as it is not need here. I am using this code in my page.xml

```
    <cms_index_index>
    <reference name="head">
                <action method="removeItem"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

But the script is still being loaded. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="head">
       <action method="removeItem">
           <type>js</type>
           <script>prototype/validation.js</script>
       </action>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

The `removeItem` method receives 2 parameters. The type of the resource and the name of the resource. You were missing the type.

Comment: It works! I new it would be something simple! thanks, will accept answer when it lets me

Comment: To remove a CSS file would i just change type to css and script to stylesheet?

Comment: Yep. Just change the type to `skin_css`